# Thumbnails for old photos are wrong in Photos app

Tags: photos, photos.app, macos

I imported a large number of old photos into iPhoto, and I then updated to the new Photos app recently. After the update, the thumbnails on the old photos are incorrect. They are just thumbnails of different pictures.

I cannot find a way to fix this. I tried launching Photos with CMD and Option held down and allowing the repair to complete. The problem persisted.

I have added an image that shows a thumbnail that doesn't match the selected photo. Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Does removing and adding again the pictures work?

Comment: How do I remove and add the picture again? Export the pictures to another location and then re-add them? I guess I'll try it for one, but that is a large task for my library size as a fix for all the pictures.

Comment: That did work. I would still like a better resolution than exporting, deleting, and then reimporting my entire 100 GB library.

Comment: If it works, make a copy of your photo library, delete everything —via the Photos app— add everything back. Be careful because if you upgraded from iPhoto the library is probably split in two: everything you had before the upgrade inside the old iPhoto library; symlinks pointing to the old library and photos after the upgrade on the new Photos app library.

Comment: Sorry, I was writing while you commented; I agree it would be better to have a way to recreate the thumbnail db.

Comment: I tried moving the Thumbnails folder out of the Photos Library package; it recreated the folder but it didn't recreate the thumbnails. The "Moment sized" thumbnail is a blank square throughout my whole Photo library now.

Comment: I wonder if I paired moving the Thumbnails folder out of the library with the library "repair" process if they would get recreated. I will try that tonight when I get home.

Answer (score 2):

### To Rebuild the Photos.app Thumbnails:

Backup your library before following these instructions.

***Delete the old thumbnails and various parts from the library:***

Quit the Photos app.

Open Finder, and go to the Photos.app Library, on my system it is called `Photos Library` and is found in the `Pictures` folder.

Now right click the library and click `Show Package Contents`.

Next delete the folders called `Previews` and `Thumbnails`.

Then delete the files called `ImageProxies.apdb`, `ImageProxies.apdb-wal`, `Library.apdb` and `Library.apdb-wal` from the `database` folder.

Lastly delete the folders `RKCloudResource`, `RKImageProxyState`, `RKMaster` and `RKVersion` from the `recovery` folder.

***Now rebuild the library***

Open the Photos app **while** pressing <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>. It will ask you to if you want to repair the library, click `Repair`. It will do a repair, then your photos will go through a reprocess/reimport process. Once finished the thumbnails will start rebuilding.

P.S. I tried this on my own Photos library, and it worked.

Comment: Is there a source where you got the list of things to delete? I'm a little nervous about deleting so many internal files of the library. How long did the thumbnail rebuild take?

Comment: Zach you should do a backup first!

Comment: @Zach Green, not really. I did a bit of research to write this answer, so there's a lot of links. I'd backup your library first, if you can't do that then don't try this solution. :) It did not take long for my library, but it only has about 300 photos because I use Capture One for my photos by default. Also I use SSD.

Answer (score 0):

Simply rotate all your photo's to the right using <kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and then to the left using <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>. This could take some time, but it isn't as hard as exporting and importing the whole library.

Comment: This isn't a reasonable solution for 30,000 photos.

Answer (score 0):

From the [discussion forums at Apple](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7017913?start=0&tstart=0):

> Are you still able to use iPhoto on your iPhoto Library?  If so run the first aid on that library with iPhoto and apply Options #1, Repair Library Permissions, #2 - Rebuild Thumbnails and #4 - Rebuild Library Database.
>
> Then open that "fixed" library with Photos to create a new Photos library.  See if that will bring the thumbnails back.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the shape of the thumbnails. 
There is an option "Display Square Thumbnails in Split view" under the View menu option. I can't be sure, but this may cause the app to redraw the thumbnails, and may resolve your problem (lets hope so anyway).

[image: View menu]